# vsftpd chroot_local_user error

Tags: ftp, chroot

When I set `chroot_local_user` to `YES` in the vsftpd configuration, I get this error in my ftp client:

```
220: (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Connected to 23.21.50.255.
Cmd: AUTH TLS
234: Proceed with negotiation.
Cmd: USER ftpaccess
331: Please specify the password.
Cmd: PASS xxxxxxxx
Could not read reply from control connection: Unknown error: 0.
```

And this in the /var/log/vsftpd.log file:

```
Wed May 16 04:51:42 2012 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "68.224.80.95"
Wed May 16 04:51:43 2012 [pid 1] [ftpaccess] OK LOGIN: Client "68.224.80.95"
```

If I remove write access to my home directory, I do not receive the error and am able to connect.  How can I enable chroot_local_user with write access to my web directory?

Comment: This could be related to using TLS with chroots, try connecting without TLS to rule out or confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same issue here and, indeed, it seems to be related to TLS and chroot...
I used to have this working on older instances of vsftpd (last checked 2.0.5).. this fails for me with 3.0.2